# Update binding target value via Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a `Control` thats visibility is bound to a viewmodel but also allows a user to close the control directly.  Ideally what I would like is for the `CloseDialog` function to check for binding on the `Visibility` and, if it exists, update the binding value (aka that of the ViewModel) directly rather than overwrite it but I am struggling how I actually update the value itself

```
public void CloseDialog()
{
    Control visibileObject = this;

    //Check to ensure we have no binding set, if we do then update the binding expression
    Binding myBinding;
#if (!SILVERLIGHT)
    myBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(visibileObject, Control.VisibilityProperty);

#else
    BindingExpression bindingExpression = visibileObject.GetBindingExpression(Control.VisibilityProperty);
    myBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
#endif

    if (myBinding != null)
    {
        //Here update binding target to be Visibility.Collapsed
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass the close request onto the VM and let it handle it? It can decide whether it can close (eg. unsaved data) and set the property if it can.

Comment: By the way, `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue` would facilitate your request but it's WPF 4/4.5 only - no SL support to my knowledge. But seriously, you're better off just changing your approach altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UpdateSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) method of the BindingExpression to update the source.

```
bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```

It will update your ViewModel property with the current value of the VisibilityProperty.

But you can also set the Visibility of your control in your CloseDialog method. If a (Two-Way)binding exists it will automatically update your property.

```
public void CloseDialog()
{
  this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: If I set `this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` then it will overwrite the VMs binding to it and I will subsequently not be able to open the dialog again

Comment: @Chris: Then I suspect your binding is `OneWay`. If you set its mode to `TwoWay` instead, the binding should update correctly instead of being overwritten (see @Niklas' answer).

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand you, but I would suggest to bind the visibility to your view model directly using a converter to convert the value of the view model to a Visibility value. If the binding is TwoWay you get the model to be updated and vice versa. This could be done in your XAML code:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.Value, 
              ElementName=MyDataProperty,
              Mode=TwoWay, 
              Converter={StaticResource ValueToVisibiltyConverter}}"
```

and the converter would do something like this in the conversion:

```
   public override object Convert(
            object value, 
            Type targetType, 
            object parameter,   
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (value.Equals("HideMe")
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public override object ConvertBack(
            object value, 
            Type targetType, 
            object parameter, 
            CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO! Convert back to view model value
    }
```